# How to host a developed web application?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have developed an web application with JSF2.0 and used the MySQL Query browser for database still i'm  running this web application in Tomcat local server(i.e. localhost:8080).

Now i want to host web application, some one could tell me how to achieve this.
The web application is developed in eclipse IDES, how to extract the project from the eclipse
and how to host along with database.

Regards.
Guruputra K M

Comment: First you read about how you can package and distribute Java applications. You read about jars, ears, wars. You read about maven or something else which would allow you to setup a sensible build. Then you read about applications servers, and search online if there is anybody happy to provide you app server to host your application. This is unlikely, so you look for hosting services which would allow you to host an application server. Having done that you install an application server and deploy there your build. Simples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are many ways to do.
You can install tomcat server and put the war in the webapp folder
This will host your webapp locally.

If you are developing something still, 
First you should add a server in eclipse. You can run the project with the added server very easily

Comment: yeah, i know this. i don't want to run my in localserver on 8080 port, but the thing is that i want run an application the link like (http://example.com) like, so please tell me how to host my application

Comment: For that you should have a domain name & a server which connects to internet always. You can buy a domain name & virtual servers from vendors like godaddy or amazon. Good luck

Comment: Thank you, i got solution for my problem